# divide multiple rows by single group of values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar dataframe to the following (but it has hundreds of stocks rather than A and B). I also do not know how many stocks will be in the dataframe.  I am trying to dividend the Index row by all stocks matched by Date column (stock A on Date 5/15/2020 dividend by INDEX on 5/15/2020 then Stock A on Date 5/16/2020 divided by INDEX on 5/16/2020, etc then Stock B on Date 5/15/2020 dividend by INDEX on 5/15/2020, etc.).  I add the answer I want in the DESIRED column but do not know how to get it.

```
d = {'Stock' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'INDEX', 'INDEX', 'INDEX']), 
 'Date' : pd.Series(['5/15/2020', '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020', \
                     '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020','5/16/2020','5/17/2020']),
 'Price' : pd.Series([10,20,30,20,40,60,2,5,10]),
'DESIRED' : pd.Series([5,4,3,10,8,6,1,1,1])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d) 
df
```

Comment: does each date contain only 1 INDEX row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Stock' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'INDEX', 'INDEX', 'INDEX']), 
 'Date' : pd.Series(['5/15/2020', '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020', \
                     '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020','5/16/2020','5/17/2020']),
 'Price' : pd.Series([10,20,30,20,40,60,2,5,10]),
'DESIRED' : pd.Series([5,4,3,10,8,6,1,1,1])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Here's a possible solution:

```
#First we build a dataframe containing only index rows
df_index = df[df.Stock == 'INDEX']

#and we get rid of those rows from the original dataframe
df = df[df.Stock != 'INDEX']

#now we merge them
df = df.merge(df_index[['Date', 'Price']], on='Date', suffixes = ['', '_index'])

#and we simply create the new column
df['hooray!'] = df.Price/df.Price_index

#If you want you can delete the column
#del df['Price_index']
```

Output:

```
    Stock   Date    Price   DESIRED     Price_index     hooray!
0   A   5/15/2020   10  5   2   5.0
1   B   5/15/2020   20  10  2   10.0
2   A   5/16/2020   20  4   5   4.0
3   B   5/16/2020   40  8   5   8.0
4   A   5/17/2020   30  3   10  3.0
5   B   5/17/2020   60  6   10  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

#data (NOTE: i've removed the desired column)
d = {'Stock' : pd.Series(['A', 'A', 'A','B', 'B', 'B', 'INDEX', 'INDEX', 'INDEX']), 
'Date' : pd.Series(['5/15/2020', '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020', \
                 '5/16/2020', '5/17/2020','5/15/2020','5/16/2020','5/17/2020']),
'Price' : pd.Series([10,20,30,20,40,60,2,5,10])}

#create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
#create emoty desired column
df['DESIRED'] = ''

#create sub dataframes for stocks and indices
stocksDf = df.loc[df['Stock'] != 'INDEX'].reset_index(drop=True)
indexDf = df.loc[df['Stock'] == 'INDEX'].reset_index(drop=True)
#loop over stocks dataframe
for i, row in stocksDf.iterrows():
    #define needed values
    stocks = stocksDf.at[i, 'Stock']
    price = stocksDf.at[i, 'Price']
    date = stocksDf.at[i, 'Date']
    #get index matching date of stock
    matchingIndex = indexDf.loc[indexDf['Date'] == date].reset_index(drop=True)
    #if doesn't exists just print no matching index
    if len(matchingIndex)==0:
        df['DESIRED'].loc[(df['Stock'] == stocks) & (df['Price'] == price) & (df['Date'] == date)] = 'No Matching Index'
    else:
        #if exists calculate Desired as Price of stock / price of index
        indexPrice = matchingIndex.at[0,'Price']
        df['DESIRED'].loc[(df['Stock'] == stocks) & (df['Price'] == price) & (df['Date'] == date)] = df['Price'] / indexPrice

#for indices just set desired as 1
df['DESIRED'].loc[df['Stock'] == 'INDEX'] =   1 

print(df)

   Stock       Date  Price DESIRED
0      A  5/15/2020     10       5
1      A  5/16/2020     20       4
2      A  5/17/2020     30       3
3      B  5/15/2020     20      10
4      B  5/16/2020     40       8
5      B  5/17/2020     60       6
6  INDEX  5/15/2020      2       1
7  INDEX  5/16/2020      5       1
8  INDEX  5/17/2020     10       1
```

Comment: @guillermo >> yes >> there will be no duplicative indexes